# Laravel Eloquent relation overwrites column?

Tags: laravel-5, orm, eloquent, relational-database

A `User` can create `Auctions` and `Auctions` can have an appending `Purchase`.

I want to fetch all `Purchases` ( the one that HE SOLD - this user created an `Auction` and someone else purchased it) from one `User` by referencing via the `Auctions` table:

Auctions

`id | user_id`

Purchases

`id | user_id | auction_id`

My `Auctions` table has a column `user_id`, which has the same name as the column `user_id` from the table `Purchases`.

I thought I can fetch all `Purchases` with the `hasManyThrough` method like this:

User Model:

```
  public function sold_purchases()
  {
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
      'App\Purchase', 'App\Auction'
      );
  }
```

It works nearly as expected BUT:

The field `user_id` from the fetched results always has the `user_id` from the `Auction` it is referenced by and not the correct `user_id` as it is in the database (In the table `Purchase`. As they have the same name I guess somehow this gets messed up.

Is there a way to give a synonym to one of those columns? Or am I doing something else wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try specifying the **aliases** with `select()` prefixed with your table names on the colliding columns (`id` & `user_id` in your case):

**User** Model:

```
public function sold_purchases()
{
     return $this->hasManyThrough(
         'App\Purchase', 'App\Auction'
     )->select([
        'purchases.id', 
        'purchases.user_id as purchase_user_id', 
        'auctions.user_id as auction_user_id', 
        'auction_id',
    ]);
}
```

Then you can do:

```
$user = User::find(1);
$userPurchase = $user->sold_purchases()->first(); // Fetch 1 to test
```

And if your **Purchase** Model has a name property you can do:

```
dd($userPurchase->name);
```

Comment: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'created_at' in order clause is ambiguous. Same I will probably get for all timestamps. I tried adding `       'auctions.created_at as auction_created_at' ` without success. Anyway this answer goes definietly in the right direction

Comment: Solved by adding another 'purchase_user' to the Purchase model and also adding the auctions.created_at to the select as well as purchases.created_at

Comment: Strangely I can't access the retrieved object variables, only like $purchase->purchase_user['name']  (not using ->name)

Comment: That's odd, how did you fetch your resultset? I'll update my answer in a sec

Comment: When I accepted your answer I was able to use the objects. Then some time later I wasn't anymore although I didn't change anything about the model. For the moment I can live with it, but I am curious what happened o.O

Comment: Very weird. If you could update your question with your models, migration & related code then I'll have a look at it later